# wordpress plugin dev, detect shortcode usage submit form from widget to that page

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, widget, shortcode

I've created a plugin and now want to create a widget containing a form that will submit to the page where my plugin shortcode is embedded from any wordpress page on the front end.

I assume that within my widget code I need to detect the page/post or permalink containing the shortcode and make that the action="" of my form.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I found this code for conditionally loading js/css based on found shortcode but not sure how to adapt to be used in my widget.

```
add_filter('the_posts', 'conditionally_add_scripts_and_styles'); // the_posts gets triggered before wp_head
function conditionally_add_scripts_and_styles($posts){
if (empty($posts)) return $posts;

$shortcode_found = false; // use this flag to see if styles and scripts need to be enqueued
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    if (stripos($post->post_content, '[code]') !== false) {
        $shortcode_found = true; // bingo!
        break;
    }
}

if ($shortcode_found) {
    // enqueue here
    wp_enqueue_style('my-style', '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('my-script', '/script.js');
}

return $posts;
}
```

Original post found here: http://beerpla.net/2010/01/13/wordpress-plugin-development-how-to-include-css-and-javascript-conditionally-and-only-when-needed-by-the-posts/

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks, Russ

Comment: Ask dev questions at [wordpress.se]. There's a typo `-&gt;` is `->`

Comment: also fixed typo that you pointed out.